# Azure List Blob by prefix in php sdk

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I use azure php sdk to use azure blob service.Right now ,I can create blob, list blob ,delete blob.But I would like to list blob by prefix.

My container name is products. In the products ,I create images. I gave the name of images.

- small/image1_small.jpg.
- medium/image1_medium.jpg.

Is it possible to list blob by blob name prefix?I found for C#. But I couldn't find for php.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the source code for [`listing blobs on GitHub`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php#L1068), you could specify various listing options, one of them is blob prefix. So you would do something like:

```
$blobListOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
$blobListOptions->setPrefix('abc/');
$result = $blobRestProxy->listBlobs('container name', $blobListOptions);
```

You can find source code for `ListBlobsOptions` here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Blob/Models/ListBlobsOptions.php

Comment: That file now lives here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/ListBlobsOptions.php